# Running query against quarter or week of the year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that works for 1 quarter. However, what if I want to do the same query but for 2nd, 3rd, and 4th quarter of the calendar year or even WEEKLY?

How can I do the same query without having to manually change the values defining the quarter or week of the year?

```
SELECT count(1), AVG(resolved_at::TIMESTAMP - created_at::TIMESTAMP) 
FROM supp_cases 
WHERE created_at::TIMESTAMP >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP 
AND resolved_at::TIMESTAMP <= '2017-03-31 23:59:59'::TIMESTAMP;

Q1 = 2017-01-01 00:00:00 TO 2017-03-31 23:59:59
Q2 = 2017-04-01 00:00:00 TO 2017-06-30 23:59:59
Q3 = 2017-07-01 00:00:00 TO 2017-09-30 23:59:59
Q4 = 2017-10-01 00:00:00 TO 2017-12-31 23:59:59
```

Comment: Look up the dateadd/datepart functions.

Comment: You are using two different columns for defining the quarter.  That seems very awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-Q') as created_at_yyyyq,
       TO_CHAR(resolved_at, 'YYYY-Q') as resolved_at_yyyyq,
       count(*)
FROM supp_cases 
GROUP BY created_at_yyyyq, resolved_at_yyyyq
ORDER BY created_at_yyyyq, resolved_at_yyyyq;
```

If you really want rows created and resolved in the same quarter, you can add:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-Q') = TO_CHAR(resolved_at, 'YYYY-Q')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using intervals, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE created_at > '2017-01-01'
 AND resolved_at < (DATE('2017-01-01') + INTERVAL '1 WEEKS');


SELECT * FROM example WHERE created_at > '2017-01-01'
 AND resolved_at < (DATE('2017-01-01') + INTERVAL '2 MONTHS');
```